# Deformation invariance of homotopy type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $\mathscr{X}\to \Delta$ be a flat family of projective varieties over the unit disk so that each fiber $X_t$ has canonical singularities and its canonical sheaf $\omega_{X_t}$ is $\mathcal{Q}$-ample.

Question: are all the fibers homotopy equivalent? If not so, are there some topological invariants (\emph{e.g.} cohomology groups) under such flat deformations?

Comment: The fibers need not be homotopy equivalent.  Consider a pencil of hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree $d\geq 5$ that specializes to a surface with an ordinary double point.  There are vanishing cycles, a Clemens-Schmid exact sequence, etc.